# Implementing pow(A, B) % C using Recursion where A, B and C are positive integers

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Below is my function which gives wrong output on some inputs(only large inputs i guess):

```
Mod(int A, int B, int C) {
    long long y = 0;
    if(B == 0)
        return 1;

    if(B%2 == 1) {
        y = (A%C * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;
    }

    else {
        y = Mod(A, B/2, C);
        y = (y*y) % C;
    }

    return (int)y;
}
```

On input A = 71045970, B = 41535484 and C = 64735492 this function returns 10848368 while the correct answer is 20805472.

In the correct program, my program line :

`y = (A%C * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;`

needs to be replaced with:

`y = A%C;
 y = (y * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;`

I am unable to differentiate between the two. To me they look essentially the same. Please tell me why my code is wrong.

Comment: if you use 
y = ((A%C) * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;
and give you the correct result, then, the problem is in the order of the operations, looks like the * have preference over %.

Comment: `%` and `*` have equal precedence, and L-R associativity.

Comment: I tried that and the outcome is same.

Comment: The result of `A%C` is of type `int` because both `A` and `C` are int. Since `Mod` also implicitly returns int the type of `A%C * Mod(...)` is also `int` which may be too small to hold the value. In the replacement, `y` is a `long long`, using it in the multiplication makes the type of `A%C * Mod(...)` also `long long`.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with operator precedence.   `*` and `%` have equal precedence and left-right associativity in C and C++.

It is because

```
y = (A%C * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;
```

does all the calculations on the right as `int`, which may overflow for large values, and then converts the result to `long long` to store it in `y`.

The form

```
y = A%C;
y = (y * Mod(A, B-1, C)) % C;
```

causes arithmetic using `long long` rather than `int` in the second statement.   The result of `Mod(A,B-1,C)` is promoted to `long long`, before doing the multiplication `(y * Mod(A, B-1, C)`, and the result is of type `long long`.   Similarly, `C` is promoted to `long long`, and the expression on the right hand side has type `long long`.

Note:  in C++ you will need to explicitly return `int` from the function, otherwise it will not compile.